# Swap mouse's Primary Button using a shortcut-key

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse

In Ubuntu mouse's Primary Button can be easily swapped between left and right from the Settings menu.

I'd like to make such change possible from a keyboard's shortcut.

Is there any way to create such shortcut? Or does it already exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the commands for toggling this behavior are

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed false
```

[image]

make a script for toggling of them like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

key="org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed"
current=$(gsettings get $key)

if [ "$current" == "true" ]; then
  gsettings set $key false
else
  gsettings set $key true
fi
```

for toggling this script needs to run.

save this script in your preferred location.
I have saved the script in `~/bin/` as `RLT.sh` (Right Left Toggling)

Make the script `RLT.sh` executable by  running below command.
`chmod +x /home/user-name/bin/RLT.sh` #replace `user-name` with yours.

now set a custom shortcut for it as you wish.

go to keyboards, add new short cut anything you wish.

[image]

I have made custom shortcut as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for running this script.
now, when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed, it toggles.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer and very comprehensive guide to do so. Thanks a lot.
(In my case it was `/bin/` rather than `~/bin/`, but I guess that might change between cmputers)

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on [UnKNOWn's response](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119612/1595727). I have modified it to fit in one line, so you can paste it directly into the keyboard shortcuts dialog:

```
bash -c 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed $([ "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed)" = "false" ] && echo "true" || echo "false")'
```

You can put this line into the config dialog for keyboard shortcuts, as follows:
[image: Ubuntu shortcut config]